# Spherical harmonics and Laplace operator

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions, special-functions

The spherical harmonic function $Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)$ is defined to be an eigenfunction of the angular part of the Laplace operator with eigenvalue $-l(l+1)$. In other words, it solves the PDE:
$$\Delta_{\theta \phi}f := \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \theta^2} + \frac{1}{\tan \theta} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta} + \frac{1}{\sin^2 \theta} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi} = -l(l+1) f.$$
I tried to check this using the Mathematica implementation of the spherical harmonics `SphericalHarmonicY`. If I plug this into the left-hand side of the above equation,

```
D[SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]] , {\[Theta], 2}] + 
 1/Tan[\[Theta]] D[SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]] , \[Theta]]  + 1/Sin[\[Theta]]^2 D[ 
   SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]] , {\[Phi], 2}]
```

I get:
$$-m(m+1)Y_l^m + \cdots.$$
In the dots, there are complicated expressions involving gamma functions and spherical harmonics. Now, it turns out that this actually does equal $-l(l+1) Y_l^m$ simply by trying out different values of $l$ and $m$, keeping $\theta$ and $\phi$ arbitrary. However, this is not at first obvious and I was wondering if there was a way to make Mathematica recognize this simplification?

I tried do use `Refine` and `Element` to tell Mathematica that $l$ and $m$ and integers, but this did not help.

Comment: Please provide Mathematica code that you've used.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment. Indeed,

```
FullSimplify[D[SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]], {\[Theta], 2}] + 
1/Tan[\[Theta]] D[SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]], \[Theta]] + 
1/Sin[\[Theta]]^2 D[SphericalHarmonicY[l, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]], {\[Phi], 2}], 
Assumptions -> {l, m} \[Element] Integers]
```

> `-m (1 + m) SphericalHarmonicY[l,  m, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + (E^(-2 I \[Phi]) Sqrt[ Gamma[1 + l - m]] ((1/Sqrt[Gamma[l - m]]) 2 E^(I \[Phi]) (1 + m) Cot[\[Theta]] Sqrt[Gamma[2 + l + m]] SphericalHarmonicY[l, 1 + m, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + ( Sqrt[Gamma[3 + l + m]] SphericalHarmonicY[l, 2 + m, \[Theta], \[Phi]])/Sqrt[ Gamma[-1 + l - m]]))/(Sqrt[Gamma[1 + l + m]])`

, but

```
N[(E^(-2 I \[Phi]) Sqrt[
  Gamma[1 + l - 
    m]] ((1/Sqrt[Gamma[l - m]]) 2 E^(I \[Phi]) (1 + 
      m) Cot[\[Theta]] Sqrt[Gamma[2 + l + m]] SphericalHarmonicY[
     l, 1 + m, \[Theta], \[Phi]] + (Sqrt[
       Gamma[3 + l + m]] SphericalHarmonicY[l, 
       2 + m, \[Theta], \[Phi]])/Sqrt[Gamma[-1 + l - m]]))/(Sqrt[
 Gamma[1 + l + m]]) /. {l -> 3, m -> 2, \[Phi] -> Pi/4, \[Theta] -> Pi/3}]
```

> `0. - 2.29947 I`

Maybe, a bug in `FullSimplify`.

Comment: In version 13 the above results in `0. - 4.59893 I`.

Comment: In 13.3.0 the result is once again - 2.29947 I.

Comment: WRI seems to use $_2F_1$  plus GPT if ever linear second order ODE methods apply. No such formula   is working as expected. Use the original operator  ####  $(1/ \sin \theta \partial_\theta (\sin \theta \partial_\thetal #) + 1/(\sin \theta)^2  \partial_{\phi \phi}  # )/ #\&)\[ e^{i m \phi} \ LegendreP\[l,m , \cos \theta)\]+ l(l+1) $  ####

Comment: @RolandF Your TEX failed.

Comment: Assuming[ 
  0 < \[Theta] < \[Pi] && 
   0 < \[Phi] < 2 \[Pi] && {l, m} \[Element] Integers && 
   l > 0, (1/Sin[\[Theta]] D[
          Sin[\[Theta]] D[#, \[Theta]], \[Theta]] + 
        1/Sin[\[Theta]]^2 D[#, \[Phi], \[Phi]] + l (l + 1) # &)[
     Exp[I m \[Phi]] LegendreP[l, m, Cos[\[Theta]]]] // FullSimplify //
    FunctionExpand] // Simplify

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the resulting expression, for general arguments, essentially one needs to apply the following identity:

https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/LegendreP2General/17/01/01/0003/

Comment: Could you elaborate your direction, giving us details and a Mathematica code? TIA.